# Unable to set variables in bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I am attempting to automate moving files from a folder to a new folder automatically every night using a bash script run from AppleScript on a schedule. I am attempting to write a bash script on Mac OSX, and it keeps failing. In short this is what I have (all my `echo`s are for error checking):

```
#!/bin/bash
folder = "ABC"
useracct = 'test'
day = date "+%d"
month = date "+%B" 
year = date "+%Y"
folderToBeMoved = "/users/$useracct/Documents/Archive/Primetime.eyetv"
newfoldername = "/Volumes/Media/Network/$folder/$month$day$year"
ECHO "Network is $network" $network
ECHO "day is $day"
ECHO "Month is $month"
ECHO "YEAR is $year"
ECHO "source is $folderToBeMoved"
ECHO "dest is $newfoldername"
mkdir $newfoldername
cp -R $folderToBeMoved $newfoldername
if [-f $newfoldername/Primetime.eyetv];
    then rm $folderToBeMoved;
fi
```

Now my first problem is that I cannot set variables at all. Even literal ones where I just make it equal some literal. All my `echo`s come out blank. I cannot grab the day, month, or year either,it comes out blank as well.

I get an error saying that -f is not found.

I get an error saying there is an unexpected end of file.

I made the file and did a `chmod u+x scriptname.sh`

I'm not sure why nothing is working at all. I am very new to this bash script on OSX, and only have experience with windows vbscript. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Assignment in bash scripts cannot have spaces around the `=` and you probably want your date commands enclosed in <s>backticks</s> `$()`:

```
#!/bin/bash
folder="ABC"
useracct='test'
day=$(date "+%d")
month=$(date "+%B")
year=$(date "+%Y")
folderToBeMoved="/users/$useracct/Documents/Archive/Primetime.eyetv"
newfoldername="/Volumes/Media/Network/$folder/$month$day$year"
ECHO "Network is $network" $network
ECHO "day is $day"
ECHO "Month is $month"
ECHO "YEAR is $year"
ECHO "source is $folderToBeMoved"
ECHO "dest is $newfoldername"
mkdir $newfoldername
cp -R $folderToBeMoved $newfoldername
if [-f $newfoldername/Primetime.eyetv]; then rm $folderToBeMoved; fi
```

With the last three lines commented out, for me this outputs:

```
Network is 
day is 16
Month is March
YEAR is 2010
source is /users/test/Documents/Archive/Primetime.eyetv
dest is /Volumes/Media/Network/ABC/March162010
```

Comment: Back ticks are evil (non-nestable). I'd use $() myself. But +1 for a good answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm very slowly learning to use `$()` myself, but it's a little hard to reprogram a 15-year-old habit.

Comment: @Isaac: it is so worth it.  I wrote a lint script that periodically crawls `~/bin` and yammers about backticks.  Expunge them!

Comment: Oh really ` is different from '. that's really good to know.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that backticks can actually be nested with backslash-escaping, but it becomes very ugly very quickly so `$()` is a much better choice.

Comment: Done. Will never use backticks. am using the $() syntax now. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

Five problems:

1. Don't put a space before or after the equal sign.
2. Use `"$(...)"` to get the output of a command as text.
3. `[` is a command. Put a space between it and the arguments.
4. Commands are case-sensitive. You want `echo`.
5. Use double quotes around variables. `rm "$folderToBeMoved"`

Comment: +1, that pretty much covers it.  #4 isn't accurate for most OS X systems though.  Since the standard setup has a case-insensitive filesystem, ECHO will work just fine.  I still wouldn't recommend it, but it's not going to cause a problem with this script.

Comment: The default filesystem on Mac OS X is case-insensitive. `ECHO` works just as well as `echo`, although for portability it is not a wise idea.

Comment: Fair enough, but then `ECHO` executes the executable, and not the bash built-in.

Answer (score 7):

`folder = "ABC"` tries to run a command named `folder` with arguments `=` and `"ABC"`. The format of command in bash is:

```
command arguments separated with space
```

while assignment is done with:

```
variable=something
```

---

- In `[ -f $newfoldername/Primetime.eyetv]`, `[` is a command (`test`)
  and `-f` and `$newfoldername/Primetime.eyetv]` are two arguments. It
  expects a third argument (`]`) which it can't find (arguments must be
  separated with space) and thus will show error.
- `[-f $newfoldername/Primetime.eyetv]` tries to run a command `[-f` with argument `$newfoldername/Primetime.eyetv]`

Generally for cases like this, paste your code in [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) and see the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

here's your amended script

```
#!/bin/bash    
folder="ABC" #no spaces between assignment    
useracct='test'    
day=$(date "+%d") # use $() to assign return value of date command to variable    
month=$(date "+%B")     
year=$(date "+%Y")    
folderToBeMoved="/users/$useracct/Documents/Archive/Primetime.eyetv"    
newfoldername="/Volumes/Media/Network/$folder/$month$day$year"    
ECHO "Network is $network" $network    
ECHO "day is $day"    
ECHO "Month is $month"    
ECHO "YEAR is $year"    
ECHO "source is $folderToBeMoved"    
ECHO "dest is $newfoldername"    

mkdir "$newfoldername"    
cp -R "$folderToBeMoved" "$newfoldername"
if [ -f "$newfoldername/Primetime.eyetv" ]; then # <-- put a space at square brackets and quote your variables.
 rm "$folderToBeMoved";
fi
```