# "var = $(<filename)" in bash script not assigning file contents

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am a beginner with bash scripts and my bash script begins with reading a file's one line content into a variable, however it returns the error

```
pid: not found
```

My script looks like:

```
pid = `cat /home/file.py`
echo $pid
```

I also tried

```
pid = $(</home/file.py)
```

and got the same error.

Comment: Remove spaces around `=` to make it `pid=$(</home/file.py)`

Comment: thank you @anubhava, that worked. I feel stupid now

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have found this for you without needing to get any humans involved.

Comment: With the title adjusted (which will further help searchability), I think this is now no longer a good choice for close-as-typo, and now a good choice for a dupe close, making it a guidepost for the better-asked question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459286/unable-to-set-variables-in-bash-script/2459863#2459863 is a better one.

Answer (score 1):

In `pid = $(</home/file.py)`, `=` and `$(</home/file.py)` is arguments for a command `pid`. It doesn't specify an assignment. For assignment you need to do:

```
var=something #without any space in-between
```